# Where is `mktexlsr.pl` coming from in the trunk TexLive source?

Tags: texlive, perl

I found that in modern `fmtutil.pl` https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/92c38ad23e396ba3c67728998a7857791d401ea8/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl#L23 `require "mktexlsr.pl"` is used, but in https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/92c38ad23e396ba3c67728998a7857791d401ea8/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive there is only `mktexlsr` shell script, no Perl version.

I found that there were [efforts to rewrite](https://github.com/norbusan/texlive-rewrite/blob/master/mktexlsr.pl) these shell scripts into Perl, but I'm struggling to find if it these new Perl scripts were finally upstreamed and where they live.

(Context: I am basically trying to build a staticperl/PAR-like package with the `tlmgr` and TexLive installation scripts from https://github.com/TeX-Live/installer/ and related scripts like `fmtutil.pl` and `updmap.pl` from https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive)

Thank you!

---

**UPD**: I found it in https://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/, but any reason why it was not placed on GitHub into https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive . Is it available anywhere in version-controlled repo in Git or SVN?

Comment: You should probalby ask on the texlive mailing list instead. https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo

Comment: There's a note in the script saying 'For future inclusion in texlive svn:' followed by svn data. I don't know if the data is just added by hand or whether the note is now obsolete as it has been included?

Answer (score 0):

After me posting a comment in https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/pull/63#issuecomment-1933091328, this file `mktexlsr.pl` got added in the GitHub repo and now lives in https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/mktexlsr.pl